# How to configure Juniper EX switch for anti-bruteforcing?

Tags: juniper, juniper-ex

How can I configure to secure my switch from brute force attacks via ssh? Can I configure something like Fail2ban?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you want to use SSH Key-based authentication and move away from user-based as much as possible, but in areas where I need to use username and password logging, I tend to standardise on the following:

```
set system login retry-options backoff-threshold 2
set system login retry-options backoff-factor 10
set system login retry-options tries-before-disconnect 3
set system ssh root-login deny
set system ssh protocol-version v2
set system ssh max-sessions-per-connection 1
set system ssh client-alive-interval 30
```

This gives you three guesses at the password, but after the 2nd wrong attempt, it will make you wait 10 seconds before having a third go.

This also stops the `root` account from being able to log in remotely (instead you can escalate to `root` via `su` in the shell later)

Be very careful with `set system login retry-options lockout-period` - it does not work per IP as fail2ban does, but instead works by username (which is pretty disappointing for a security feature).

This means if someone bruteforces your legitimate username, they will lock your account out continuously and you will be unable to log into your own device.

This raises a final point which is to make your network infrastructure username unique eg: not your email address prefix, and not generic accounts such as `admin`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Juniper EX to test this on and it is for an SRX, but JunOS is built to be standardized across platforms, so these steps may work on the EX.

[How to block Telnet and SSH Brute Force log-in attacks](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB28968&actp=search)